# Semantic 'talking' CSS navigation with captions

Tags: html, css, navigation, semantics

What's the best way to mark up a navigation menu with captions for each element? (I think the term 'speaking' is attributable to Smashing Magazine, see http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/02/26/navigation-menus-trends-and-examples/)

A definition list seems most appropriate, something like:

```
<dl id="menu">
    <dt>About</dt>
    <dd>Our work, mission, history and people</dd>
    <dt>Events</dt>
    <dd>We put on workshops, talks and debates</dd>
    <dt>Media</dt>
    <dd>See videos from our archive of past events</dd>
    <dt>Contact</dt>
    <dd>Get in touch with us for further information</dd>
</dl>
```

But I can't think how to style it to look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Etd4K.png
without extra DIVs around each menu item which I don't think is valid HTML.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any code yet? If yes, could you share it with us? We can't help if we dont know whats going on.

Comment: Well the code would just be a basic definition list; see above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Afh9N/***

The CSS isn't pretty...

```
dt, dd {
    width:120px;
    padding:0 10px;
    border-left:2px solid #333;
    float:left;
}

dt {
    margin-left:-120px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

dt:first-child {
    margin:0;
}

dd {
    position:relative;
    top:20px;
    font-family:verdana;
    font-size:9px;
    left:-142px;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a `definition list` is best way to go about this.

I would style a `ul` and use `spans` for the "speaking part".  Something like this:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>About <span>Our work, mission, history and people</span></li>
    <li>Events <span>We put on workshops, talks and debates</span></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
li{display:block; float:left; background:blue; border:1px; color:white; 
   font-family:arial; font-size:1.25em; width:150px; padding:1em;}
span{display:block; font-size:.7em;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Yzx8K/1/

Comment: Seems semantic to me. The title of the page is 'Contact' and the description is 'Get in touch with us for further information'. I can't think of a more semantic way of coding it (without HTML5).

Comment: Agreed, @MrMisterMan.  It is definitely semantic.  (That's why I qualified and said "the most semantic".)  However, to remove ambiguity, I edited the above to say not the best way.  Thx for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<ul>
<li><h2>Menu Item 1</h2> Menu Item 1 "Speaking Text"</li>
<li><h2>Menu Item 2</h2> Menu Item 2 "Speaking Text"</li>
<li><h2>Menu Item 3</h2> Menu Item 3 "Speaking Text"</li>
<li><h2>Menu Item 4</h2> Menu Item 4 "Speaking Text"</li>
</ul>
```

Then you can style the list elements into the menu however you like.  The header in each list element provides both a style target and a semantic way to show the importance of the main "Menu Item" text.

Comment: That's what I've got at the moment, and seems like the least worst solution. I just wondered if that was the accepted way of doing it because a definition list seems ideal!